# backbonejs + angularjs integration

Tags: angularjs, backbone.js

do you have any experience with integrating AngularJS component into existing BackboneJS application?
Could you just briefly give me some help, what should I do to make it work?

Thank you

Igor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make it work after all
for the future reference - this gist helped me a lot: https://gist.github.com/dgs700/6197687

anyway, Charles is right - it is definitely not nice to combine these two frameworks (in my case, it was not my call to do so...)

Answer (score 0):

Angular scope will overcome the backbone scope. There is no point using those two frameworks on the same project. Mixing those two will result in a poor designed project.

Either stick to Backbone or replace it with Angular.